# WxPython File Dialogs

Tags: python, wxpython, tkinter

I am building an application in wxPython and i read somewhere on a blog that you cannot use wx.FD_OPEN and wx.FD_SAVE on the same application at the same time, is this true?

If this is true, does this mean i have to move to Tkinter?

**EDIT**: What i currently have.

```
      SAVE_FILE_ID = wx.NewId()
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.saveFile, id=SAVE_FILE_ID)

      LOAD_FILE_ID = wx.NewId()
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.loadFile, id=LOAD_FILE_ID)

      accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('O'), LOAD_FILE_ID ),
                                       (wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('S'), SAVE_FILE_ID )])

      self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

      def saveFile(self, event):
        saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save As", "", "", 
                                      "Python files (*.py)|*.py", 
                                      wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)

        self.text.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.GetPath())
        event.Skip()

      def loadFile(self, event):
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", 
                                      "Python files (*.py)|*.py", 
                                      wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

        self.text.LoadFile(openFileDialog.GetPath())
        event.Skip()
```

Comment: 1) Yes, [that's true](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.FileDialog.html). 2) Not really. why do you think that? Open and Save are different dialogs for different purposes

Comment: Well Open and Save as are in the same menu in my program, how can i make both dialogs work via my accelerator? It won't work with load but it will work with save, simply because save comes first in my code.

Comment: @vjgaero I think you misunderstood. You can have *separate* Open and Save dialogs no problem. This is what you're doing in your code. What you can't do is have *one dialog that both opens and saves* (i.e. one dialog with the style `wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_SAVE`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. When I put this code into something that actually runs, it works fine for me:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial", size=(500,500))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        SAVE_FILE_ID = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.saveFile, id=SAVE_FILE_ID)

        LOAD_FILE_ID = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.loadFile, id=LOAD_FILE_ID)

        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('O'), LOAD_FILE_ID ),
                                         (wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('S'), SAVE_FILE_ID )]
                                        )
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def loadFile(self, event):
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", 
                                       "Python files (*.py)|*.py", 
                                       wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        openFileDialog.ShowModal()
        openFileDialog.GetPath()
        openFileDialog.Destroy()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def saveFile(self, event):
        saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save As", "", "", 
                                       "Python files (*.py)|*.py", 
                                       wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        saveFileDialog.ShowModal()
        saveFileDialog.GetPath()
        saveFileDialog.Destroy()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm using wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Python 2.6.6 on Windows 7

Comment: I compared the code and i realized i wasnt .ShowModal()

cheers.